# How to take an action on 'No such file or directory' error

Tags: perl

I created script which is supposed to delete files and/or folders in Perl.
I'm processing it with commands like:

```
my $command = "find ". $folderName." -type f ".$mtimeOption." -exec rm '{}' \\;"; 
execLinuxCommand($command);
```

`ExecLinuxCommand` adds errors into `@errors`.

```
my ($stdout, $stderr) = capture {
    system ($command);
};  

if ($stderr) {
    $stderr =~ s/\s+$//;
    $ic->log(domain=>"lifecycle",level=>"error",message=>"ERROR: $stderr", evalcontext=>$ic);
    push @errors, { command => $command, error => $stderr, level=> "ERROR" };               
}
```

Then there is `processCommandsErrors`

```
sub processCommandsErrors {

 my ($ic) = @_;

 if (@errors) {
    my $errorMessage = "There were " . ($#errors + 1) . " errors during cleanup task:\n";

    for my $i ( 0 .. $#errors ) { 
        $errorMessage .= ($i + 1) . ". $errors[$i]{level}:\n"; 
                    
        $errorMessage .= "\tCommand: $errors[$i]{command}\n"; 
        $errorMessage .= "\tError: $errors[$i]{error}\n"; 
    }
            
    die($errorMessage);
 }
}
```

What I want to do is to die on any other error except `No such file or directory` error. For this error I would only want to log that the file/folder does not exist.

Now the question: Is there more elegant way of catching `No such file or directory` error within  'processCommandsErrors' than:

```
$errors[$i]{error} == 'No such file or directory'
```

Comment: Unrelated: For the last part in your `find`, `-exec rm '{}' \;`, you may want to checkout the option `-delete` instead.

Comment: Why not use File::Find(::Rule) and `unlink` instead? Then there's no need to play around with the shell and capture STDOUT/STDERR.

Comment: Add a quick test for the directory existing - if it does, bail, else log and continue.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever to use a shell command in a Perl program to perform tasks that Perl can do, and then try to reinvent error reporting in Perl. Use `File::Find` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this URL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326766/what-are-the-standard-error-codes-in-linux), you might check `errno` instead:

```
errno -ls
...
ENOENT 2 No such file or directory
...
```

This looks more elegant than checking the whole string indeed.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  $errors[$i]{error} == 'No such file or directory'
> ```

This doesn't actually work. It will throw a warning. String comparisons need `eq`, not `==`. You probably want a pattern match anyway, because the message might contain more information, or a line break.

Comment: yes you're right I used index instead. what I meant was that if there exists something like error number ... or whatever